# How do I make a bow charge animation on roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

I can make the animation, but how do you make it so that it plays the animation to charge the bow, but keeps the arms in the position when the arrow is drawn back as you hold your mouse? Also, I'm using R15 rig type for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause an animation using the [AdjustSpeed](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/AnimationTrack/AdjustSpeed) function of the [AnimationTrack](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/AnimationTrack). 1 is the default speed, 0 should pause your animation, and a negative speed should reverse it.

```
Animation:AdjustSpeed(-1) -- Animation reversed
Animation:AdjustSpeed(0)  -- Animation paused
Animation:AdjustSpeed(1)  -- Animation playing normally
```